# Пополнение жизней спустя некоторое время. Unity

Tags: unity3d

Как реализуется механика пополнение жизней спустя некоторое время в Unity, например, через 30 минут идёт пополнение на + 1 жизнь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того что вы имеете ввиду:
если это происходит **не вовремя игры**
то вам нужно хранить время когда игрок вышел
при запуске вычислять количество минут и добавлять жизни исходя из это
если же это происходит во время игры можно использовать корутины

```
IEnumerator  UpdateHealth()
{
    int time = 30*60;
    while(playerHealth < maxPlayerHealth)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        playerHealth+=1;
    }
}
```

потом в коде где вам нужно вызываете этот метод

```
StartCorutine(UpdateHealth());
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!